# Generic UITableView and NSFetchedResultsController, inheriting From UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to draft a reusable class that basically become reusable to several entities that have almost same implementation. 
Basically I will have several `UIViewController`s each will contain `UIView` that holds `UITableView` with its custom parameters for different entities managed by the same `managedObjectContext` but with reusable `NSFetchedResultsController`.

**First question**:  is my approach is retaining cycle for `UITableView`?, so I have used `weak var tableView: UITableView` in my delegate class that inherits from `CoreManager` and will be initialized in the `UIView` with the implemented `UITableView` to handle all the invariances in the `TableViewDataSource`. I have doubts about that approach and I would like to have some guidance on how to implement it so I won't introduce memory leaks.

**Second question**: In my `TableViewManager` class is basically I will try to explicitly implement my custom code that will end up be in the custom `UIView`, also I am not sure if that is a good approach.

**Note: Please forgive my limited experience, also the code below is just a draft and incomplete.**

```
class CoreManager<ManagedObject: NSManagedObject> : NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
    var entityName: String?
    weak var managedObject : ManagedObject?
    lazy var authManager = AuthManager()
    var fetchPredicate: NSPredicate?
    var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ManagedObject> = NSFetchRequest<ManagedObject>(entityName: ManagedObject.entity().managedObjectClassName)
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<ManagedObject>
    init(entityName: String, fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ManagedObject>, sectionNameKeyPath: String?, cacheName: String?) {
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest:  fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: cacheName)
        super.init()
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        do { try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
        }
    }
    func setPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate){
        fetchPredicate = predicate
    }
}
```

**The piece of code related to question one**

```
class TableViewDataSource: CoreManager<NSManagedObject>,UITableViewDataSource{
    weak var tableView: UITableView!
    func referenceTableView(tableview: UITableView){
        self.tableView = tableview
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
            return 0
        }
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
    //FIXME: IMPLEMENT DEQUEUE CELL
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if let count = fetchedResultsController.sections?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 1
    }
    var identifier : String?
    func cellIdentifierString() -> String {
        return identifier ?? ""
    }
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        let section = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
        switch type {
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(section, with: .fade)
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertSections(section, with: .automatic)
        case .update:
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .move:
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        @unknown default:
            print()
        }
    }
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        case .update:
            guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        case .move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
            } default: return
        }
    }
}
```

```
protocol TableViewManagerDelegate: class {
    func handleDelete(at indexPath: IndexPath)
    func handleSwipeAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration
}
```

```
class TableViewManager: TVDelegation, TableViewManagerDelegate {
    //FIXME: Implement deleting
    func handleDelete(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
    //FIXME: Implement Actions
    func handleSwipeAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration{
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Action", handler: { [weak self] action, view, completion in
                completion(true)
            })
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
        return configuration
    }
}
```

**Code below and above related to question two.**

```
class TVDelegation: TableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    weak var delegateManager : TableViewManagerDelegate?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section]
            return currentSection.name
        }
        return nil
    }
    //FIXME: - IMPLEMENT NAVIGATION TO DETAILCONTROLLER
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
       let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") {[weak self]  action, view , completion in
            self?.delegateManager?.handleDelete(at: indexPath)
            completion(true)
        }
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "trash")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        return swipeConfig
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        return delegateManager?.handleSwipeAction(at: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In concept this looks pretty OK but the code may be a bit hard to understand without a bit more context. It would help if you added how you would like to use this class, what is the static part and what parts are supposed to change.

The table view does not need to be weak as long as the table view itself is not accessing its owner class. And I believe it is not accessing it in your case.

What I would expect from you is to have such an interface that you do the static part through constructor. You would have for instance:

```
TableViewManager {
    let tableView: UITableView
    let fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController

    init(tableView: UITableView, fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.fetchResultController = fetchResultController
    }
}
```

From interface point of view this looks enough for static part. You could design sections and cells inside the class along with handling deletes, insertions and more.

Then your view controller would look perhaps like

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var tableViewManager: TableViewManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewManager = TableViewManager(tableView: tableView, fetchResultController: MyManagedObject.buildFetchResultController(...))
    }

}
```

Naturally now the dynamic part is missing. I would go with creating custom delegates like:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tableViewManager = TableViewManager(tableView: tableView, fetchResultController: MyManagedObject.buildFetchResultController(...))
       tableViewManager.delegate = self
   }

extension MyViewController: TableViewManagerDelegate {
    // ... all the dynamic part goes in here
}
```

But you might as well just go with subclasses of `TableViewManager` or with injecting some other classes, data providers and controllers... The choice here is completely yours.

So to answer the first question: No, there should be no retain cycle between your classes and table view so there is no need for `weak` reference.

But the second question is completely opinion based. The best suggestion I can give you is to start with interface. First design how you would like to use your tool from outside, then build the logic inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, You got me on the right track. Basically I was trying to achieve your recommendations. I got it to preliminary testing and it is working as I expected. :) I confirmed your answer.